# Which UID/GID is free for new package

Tags: package-management, uid, rpm-spec

After reading https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222376/246754 How rpm ensure that no uid/gid clash with each other ?

What I am looking is similar to https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/68196a61c26748d3e53a6803de3d2f8c69f27831/nixos/modules/config/users-groups.nix#L640-L642 (given for comparison)

I have though to building a VM and take the /etc/passwd to see taken uid. It doesn't fully anser my need because 174 is not their by default.
Again nix also reserve some uid like 0 for root https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/commit/dba1d48b7897c49e5df9430c6b60f17e03ec361e and I can see the list without building a VM or can query with the cli. They also have an allocator for id so I don't have to manage it.

This is a scriptlet run when rebuilding /etc/passwd

PS: I have tagged rpm-spec because the linked question is about RPM but the problem is more likely to happen to other tools like apt, yum, pacman, brew...
If you have knowledge for other system please create another question and answer it (to keep Q&A style) or comment

Comment: The answer you linked to has a higher-voted sibling which points to [Fedora’s best practices](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging%3aUsersAndGroups); do you need any more information than that? It includes RPM scriptlets to take care of user and group creation as necessary, without pre-allocating ids.

Comment: Every distribution has own rules. E.g. 0-99 may be hardcoded (the same for all systems), 100-499 may be allocable by distribution (e.g. adduser), and 500-999 for syste administration. (note: there are many variations). Because in /etc/passwd and in /etc/groups you get the allocated ID, you know what is free.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi so this means that rpm on another distro won't behave as expected ? > Because in /etc/passwd and in /etc/groups you get the allocated ID, you know what is free
ok but it might be a bight of scripting to get unused id.

Comment: @StephenKitt In this article > *Soft static allocation* say to find an unused id but that is my question. From what I read you will need to read all rpm spec. I can't find with `rpm -q` something that say this package require this id. I could grep but it will be mostly like reading all very quickly.

Comment: @Et7f3XIV why do you want to use soft static allocation rather than dynamic allocation? If you want soft static allocation, you’re not supposed to find an id yourself in your scriptlet, you’re supposed to use a pre-agreed id, and the process for obtaining one varies from one distribution to another.

Comment: See also: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-managing_users_and_groups  (and you may just allocate manually for system: 250 and above, and for users 5000 and above. System should never go so high (or you have special needs (a very special system), but so you know what you are doing).

Comment: @StephenKitt I didn't mean to find an id in the scriptlet but how was the process on the distro side to find an id. I don't want specially soft static allocation but this point wasn't clear.

Comment: Thanks @Giacomo Catenazzi the link given answer my question: Maintainer keep a list somewhere. If you want you can put it in answer for marking as accepted.

Comment: @Et7f3XIV my point is really that if you want to avoid being tied to a specific distribution, you should avoid pre-allocated ids altogether and use dynamic allocation. That way you don’t need to figure out who to contact to get an id, and your RPM can be made to work across distributions. Put another way, avoid bureaucracy you don’t need ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt dynamic allocation isn't deterministic it will depends on the order of installation of package. I imagine the case where I have file with a specific owner but untar it on another machine where packages are installed in swapped order and thus the tarball isn't readable without chown-ing

Comment: @Et7f3XIV `tar` uses user/group names rather than ids as far as possible, so the allocated id doesn’t matter in those scenarios.

Comment: @StephenKitt sshfs doesn't seems to handle it

Comment: @Et7f3XIV `sshfs` supports id maps for users and groups, but I’m curious about a scenario where you need consistent ids across `sshfs`!

Answer (score 1):

Usually we refer to users/groups by their name, not their UID/GID.

Packages that have their own user will call `useradd` or `adduser` with the `--system` tag.  This will create a new user with an unused UID/GID in the range for system users (usually 100-999).

For example, I'm on a debian system, and this exists in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst` (Debian's equivalent of the RPM-SPEC scriptlet you described).

```
if ! getent passwd sshd >/dev/null; then
    adduser --quiet --system --no-create-home --home /run/sshd --shell /usr/sbin/nologin sshd
fi
```

OpenSSH never hard-codes the UID/GID of user `sshd`, it does a lookup on that name.

Comment: I see in this exemple a fixed id for sshd https://gitlab.com/redhat/centos-stream/rpms/openssh/-/blob/c9s/openssh.spec#L11-12 on redhat repository.